# tinymce line break after reach character limit per line

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I want to force user to go new line when type 50 chars per line in tinyMCE editor. Here I wrote the setup code. But it doesn't work. Any one tell me what was the wrong/ or corrections?

```
tinymce.init({
 selector: 'textarea#submitterms',
    width: 670,
  plugins: "filemanager",
    setup: function(ed){
        ed.on('KeyDown',function(ed, evt) {
            chars_without_html = $.trim(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")).length;                                
            if(chars_without_html>15){
                ed.content = ed.content.replace(/<br\s*\/>/gi, "<br />");
                ed.stopPropagation();
                ed.preventDefault();                   

            }
        });
    }
});
```